# Disutils setup on windows fails or bad install?

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, cython, anaconda

I'm building a python (C/Cython) extension on top of **Anaconda windows 64** bits distribution. The setup (*distutils.msvc9compiler.find_vcvarsall*) is looking for the correct compiler, it fails and drops me the dramatic: '**unable to find vcvarsall.bat**'

I can track the setup is looking for a key in the registry:

```
Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC
```

but my computer only has 11.0, 12.0 and 8.0 with the same pattern as above in the registry. I've tried to uninstall all the visual c++ 2008 versions I could find, tried to re-install the same 2008 version from MS web site (as it looks like the vc 9.0 is the 2008 64 bits version) but nothing changes.

I cannot see the expected 9.0 nor the undesirable 8.0 disappear...

any hint ?

---

P.S.: I've got another python extension, built using scons instead of distutils, it works perfectly. So I guess it's rather a configuration issue for the setup than an installation issue. Probably scons doesn't scan the registry?

TIA

Comment: You should be able to use the [Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) with setuptools.

Comment: fixed:(1) install compiler as mentionned by @eryksun, (2) add correct path in you system environment variables up to the actual compiler you want ($USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64) (3) copy the missing vcvarsall.bat from vcvars64.bat in bin directory

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 are not necessary if you use setuptools. Python 2.7 is distributed with pip / setuptools.